# how to fix the column text in html table

Tags: html, css

I have two columns in a table. First column contains the fixed text. The second column's text expands when the checkbox is clicked. The issue is that when the second column's text expands, the first column's text moves up/down. How can I fix the first column text?

```css
<HEAD>
  <STYLE>
  div.c220{ width:220px; overflow:hidden; }
  /*div.c150{ width:150px; overflow:hidden; }
  div.c70{ width:170px; overflow:hidden; }*/

  .inputs {
    display: none;
  }

  .foo:checked + .inputs {
    display: initial;
  }

  .tab { margin-left: 20px; }

  </STYLE>
</HEAD>
```

```html
<html>
<body>

  <table style="width:100%">

    <tr>
      <td><div class="c220"><p><B>THIS TEXT SHOULD NOT MOVE</B></p>
        <form><input type="checkbox">This text should not move when the model checkbox is clicked</form></div></td>

        <td><div class="c220"><p><B>MODEL:</B></p>
          <form action="foo">
            <input type="checkbox" class="foo"> Model #
            <div class="inputs">            
              <input type="text" size="12"><BR>
              <input type="checkbox">See Diagram Attached       
            </div> 
          </form>
        </div><br>

        <div class="c220"><p><B>ANOTHER MODEL:</B></p>
          <form action="foo">
            <input type="checkbox" class="foo"> Model #
            <div class="inputs">            
              <input type="text" size="12"><BR>
              <input type="checkbox">See Diagram Attached       
            </div> 
          </form>
        </div>
      </div></td>      
    </tr>
  </table>
  <hr />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can start with fixing the markup, where there are start tags with no end tags, two start tags after each other, like `<td><td>`, which isn't proper,and the same with end tags.

Answer (score 1):

you can set static height too div inside td

Comment: @familyGuy Static heights is not a good solution as it most likely will cause issues with unexpected overflows

Comment: @LGSon can you please suggest another solution? Thanks!

Comment: @familyGuy When you addressed what I commented below the question you can let me know and I'll have a look

Comment: @familyGuy can you change align inside td? https://jsfiddle.net/0xtmqmje/1/

here is one more solution, with out height

Answer (score 1):

Setting `vertical-align: top;` to the first table cell might help:

```css
<HEAD>
  <STYLE>
  div.c220{ width:220px; overflow:hidden; }
  /*div.c150{ width:150px; overflow:hidden; }
  div.c70{ width:170px; overflow:hidden; }*/

  .inputs {
    display: none;
  }

  .foo:checked + .inputs {
    display: initial;
  }

  .tab { margin-left: 20px; }

  </STYLE>
</HEAD>
```

```html
<html>
<body>

  <table style="width:100%">

    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;"><div class="c220"><p><B>THIS TEXT SHOULD NOT MOVE</B></p>
        <form><input type="checkbox">This text should not move when the model checkbox is clicked</form></div></td>

        <td><div class="c220"><p><B>MODEL:</B></p>
          <form action="foo">
            <input type="checkbox" class="foo"> Model #
            <div class="inputs">            
              <input type="text" size="12"><BR>
              <input type="checkbox">See Diagram Attached       
            </div> 
          </form>
        </div><br>

        <div class="c220"><p><B>ANOTHER MODEL:</B></p>
          <form action="foo">
            <input type="checkbox" class="foo"> Model #
            <div class="inputs">            
              <input type="text" size="12"><BR>
              <input type="checkbox">See Diagram Attached       
            </div> 
          </form>
        </div>
      </div></td>      
    </tr>
  </table>
  <hr />
</body>
</html>
```